# How to control node/content access in drupal 6.X?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I had a site created in drupal 6. All its contents are placed as Page Nodes. I created a user with editor role and given following permissions

access content
administer content types
adminsiter node
edit any page content
edit own page content

I want this user to **only edit the content pages** already **created by another user** ***do not want to remove/delete content/node*** from the site.

How can I do this. I tried

nodeaccess-6.x-1.3.zip
node_privacy_byrole-6.x-1.6.zip

also tried content_access-6.x-1.2.zip(but not find any settings for this module ?). Please help me to solve this issue.

thanks in advance.

Step1.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i don't know if there is a modules that support adding permissions on node delete or not but try the following.....

- first we need to create a module (don't worry ist easy) that generate a new permission which you can give to any users role lets call this permission "node delete permission"

  1- go to /sites/all/modules

  2- create a new folder with name "node_delete_permission" and create files inside this folder
  with the following names "node_delete_permission.info" && "node_delete_permission.module"

  3- open node_delete_permission.info and add the following inside it :

  ```
  name = node delete permission
  description = node delete permission
  core = 6.x
  ```

  4- now open node_delete_permission.module and add the following code inside it

  ```
  <?php

  /**
  * Implementation of hook_perm()
  */
  function node_delete_permission_perm() {
    return array("node delete permission") ; 
  } 
  /**
  * Implementation of hook_form_alter
  */
  function node_delete_permission_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
       if($form_id == 'node_admin_content') {
         if (!user_access('node delete permission')) {            
            unset($form['admin']['options']['operation']['#options']['delete']); 
         }
       }      
  }
  ```

  5- now enable your new module from (admin/build/modules)  and go to (/admin/user/permissions) .. make sure that you have a new permission generated called "node delete permission"

  if its ok...lets go to the next step

  6- go to you theme "page.tpl.php" and add the following code at the top of the this file

  ```
  <?php
  $arg1 = arg(1) ; 
  $node_path = url( 'node/'.$arg1 , array('absolute' => TRUE)) ;
  if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) == 'delete' && !user_access('node delete permission')){
  drupal_set_message('<div class="message error" > You don\'t have the permission 
     to delete node </div>') ;  
  header("Location: {$node_path}") ; 
  }
  ?>
  ```

now you can give this permission to any user role you want from (/admin/user/permissions)

NOTE:

1- its not 100% the drupal way but i think its useful in ur case

2- i didn't test this code so you may found a syntax error or something...you can get back to me if you found this

3- i hav a bad english i know and im sorry for this

Comment: Thank you for the custom module, but it still not working as the way !. any user without **administer nodes** permission cant view or edit content pages (nodes). If we enable this permission the user can simply delete any nodes. Is it possible to override this with above code ? that is if I want to create a user as editor, I am forced to give the above said permission to view content. I want this user only to edit not to delete any node ! pls hlp.

Comment: yes, I tried but its not giving the output... I gone through step by step and got a sytax error in line no 4. right paranthesis was missing which is corrected(page.tpl.php). from ../admin/content/node when I check page, select delete and press update it asks for confirmation and whooopsss its delete the page. no change ..

Comment: sorry i don't understand you well...but if you want the a group of users (role) to edit only nodes and not able to delete this you can do it by drupal built in permission....


just go to admin/user/permissions

1- disable 

"delete any story content"
"delete any page content"
... etc

2- enable 

"edit any page content"
"edit any store content"
...etc

Comment: I got a user role with **access content**, **administer nodes**, **edit any page content**, & **edit own page content**. But user with this role can still delete the node... is there any way to make this role only **editable** ? ......hope I am not confusing you.!

Comment: ok i understand you now...my code is doing what you are looking for... i modified my code and i fixed the syntax problem...can you test this now...after enabling the module and add the code to page.tpl.php (don't give the user role the permission "node delete permission")...make it disabled if you want this user role not to delete the node...test the new code and im waiting your reply here :)

Comment: sorry i forgot to add <?php before the page.tpl.php code...try again now

Comment: make it disabled if you want this user role not to delete the node = hope this means not to check it(or enable) anyway I not enabled this permission for the user, still this user with **administer node** can delete the any node.

Comment: yes don't check this.....and i tested this code my self and its working...try to clear the cache and make sure that you added the code to the right page.tpl.php file...im sure its working now i tested it....don't try to delete the node with the super account...just logout and login with the editor account and try to delete the node again...you will see the delete button but when you click this button you will be redirect to with error message that tell you "you are not able to delete node"...check ur code and try again

Comment: the user you checked does contain **administer node** permission ?.. I will try and let you know the result ...thanks for giving a big help..

Comment: yes...and the user can see "delete" button which mean he can delete the node but when he click on this button he redirect with error message...don't forget to clear the cache... its will be better if you give me of the url of the delete confirmation page...is that like this http:// yoursitename.com/node/24/delete ?

Comment: I addedd two pics above pls see it and let me know am I right!

Comment: no... this module will restrict the delete operation if you deleted the node from its edit page ...something like this... "node/23/edit" if the user will delete the node from the node it self it will be restricted...but from the nodes admin page no...let me think about it.... just make sure that the user when he try to delete the node from node edit page..he is restricted...if its working lets go to the next step...sorry for my bad english

Comment: + i edited node_delete_permission.module code ... copy the new code into your node_delete_permission.module file then disable and enable the module again (or clear the cache)...and try to delete a new node from (admin/content/node) or from (node/23/edit) page..and tell me if its working now

Comment: this worksssss ! thank you very much for giving a consistent help. It will remove the delete option from the drop down.... thank u once again...it was a great experience in drupal module developemnt.....

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the content permissions module that ships with CCK , should give you control over which field in the Page content type can be viewed , created, edited or deleted

Comment: I want the user not to delete the specific node. even if I enabled the **node_privacy_byrole** and marked the role only to edit ! still the user can simply select delete from dropdown and once clicked update the node/content is gone ? please help ....